# Deinit never called

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, deinit

I'm creating a ViewController object an pushing it to a navigation controller.
When the object is being popped from the stack - it is not being release and Deinit is not being called. What can be the reason for that?

Here's the code that pushes:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(CustomViewController(), animated: true)
```

And here's the code that pops:

```
 self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: Instead of deinit you have to use dealloc to clean up all allocated resources and like this.

Comment: I'm using Swift - so Deinit should be used - no?

Comment: Maybe you have strong reference cycles in the `CustomViewController`. Can you provide more information about your view controller?

Comment: It's nothing special. It holds a TableViewController (it's the datasource and delegate) and a UISearchDisplayController

Comment: But, still @godmoney, seeing is believing. We don't know what your datasource/delegate methods are doing and the devil is in the details as they say.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Can a strong reference cycle be ruled out if none show up in the leaks instrument?

Comment: If you are using breakpoints to determine that `deinit` is never called, be aware that breakpoints in `deinit` behave differently than anywhere else in your code! [Breakpoints will only work in `deinit` if there is an executable line of code ahead of them.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33788952/35690)

Answer (score 76):

I had similar problem. I added empty `deinit` method to my class and added breakpoint:

```
deinit {

}
```

As result it's never called.
As soon as I add some code to the body it started working as expected:

```
deinit {
    print("deinit called")
}
```

So be sure that your `deinit` method isn't empty.
PS. I am using Swift 2, Xcode 7.1

Comment: I had the exact same problem as you. I found out that this happens because [breakpoints will only work in `deinit` if there is an executable line of code ahead of them.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33788952/35690)

Comment: That's pretty strange

Comment: @Duan It is a part of compiler optimisation wherein the empty methods without implementation are skipped in a final binary.

Comment: To avoid this issue without writing a `deinit` method you can create a symbolic breakpoint on `ClassName.deinit`. There's a good explanation how to do it here: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/xcode-breakpoint-wizardry/

Answer (score 58):

Do any of your classes, or properties they contain make a reference to the view controller you've popped?

If your UIViewController has created an instance of an object, which in turn makes a 'strong' reference to that view controller (e.g. a reference that's not explicitly declared 'weak' or 'unowned'), and your view controller keeps a strong reference to that object as well, neither will be deallocated. That's called a strong reference cycle, documented here (a must read for serious Swift developers):

[The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.0.1): Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

Closures are a more insidious case where you can get into trouble.

One thing you might try as an experiment is pushing the controller and popping it *before* you do anything in viewDidLoad or in the initialization, and see if the deinit method is being called.  If it is, then you should be able to incrementally discover what you're doing that's leading to the symptom you're seeing.

Another thing that can thwart diagnosis (as other answers have pointed out), which I learned the hard way, is that the debugger breakpoint won't be taken for deinit() if the deinit method contains no executable statements, because the OS or compiler optimizes the deinit invocation away if it's empty, so at least put a print statement there if you want to verify deinit() is getting called.

Comment: Agreed.  The ARC reading was very helpful as well.  I was bitten by referring to "self" in a closure and not adding a specific capture list of "[unowned self]" . Thanks!

Comment: This led me to making sure my `delegate` was declared `weak`. Something I usually do but missed on this occassion

Answer (score 18):

I was using this tutorial [Custom TabBar](http://swiftiostutorials.com/tutorial-custom-tabbar-storyboard/) with a custom seque on the given page. The memory problem was due a subview which had a strong reference the the parent viewcontroller.

```
class WBMNewsFeedV: UIView
{
   var parentVC:WBMHomeTabVC!
}
```

> WBMNewsFeedV - subclass
>
> parentVC:WBMHomeTabVC - parent class ViewController

I changed it to :

```
class WBMNewsFeedV: UIView
{
    weak var parentVC:WBMHomeTabVC!
}
```

So, the strong reference was nested inside a subviews and not visible at first. Hope this helps anyone. After the change deinit was always called in

> WBMHomeTabVC

Comment: Had same problem. To find the references I searched for `self` in my ?`ViewController` finding all places where I have passed it as reference to be stored in a delegate variable. Apparently one of three was not set as `weak`

Comment: @Sunkas that was a good suggestion for how to find the culprit references

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue when the NotificationCenter was holding a strong reference to the presented view controlled and thus it was never getting released. So I had to add **[weak self]** to the block like this:

(in the viewDidLoad)

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .showFoo, object: nil, 
  queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (notification) in
    if let foo = notification.userInfo?["foo"] as? Foo {
            self?.afooButton!.setImage(UIImage(named: "foo"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

add some line code of in deinit. If You put breakpoint at Empty deinit ,compiler will not stop you there 
put this:

```
deinit {
print("any thing")
}
```

It will work ;)

Answer (score 7):

I had a timer in my view controller, running every minute to update a label. I put a call in deinit to invalidate the timer, which I'm pretty sure is what I've always done in Objective-C (in dealloc) and it's worked. But it seems a little different in Swift so I moved the time creation/invalidation code to viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear (which makes more sense really) and everything seems fine now!

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into a similar issue. My problem appears to have been caused by a strong reference to a control that had delegate assignment not specified as 'weak' with a class type protocol.

Comment: Ignoring "me too" part this actually may be an answer - if you are reviewing and are swift expert please see if "strong reference ... not 'weak'..." could be possible reason for problem in the question.

Comment: Winner! Had an `@objc protocol` and forgot to mark is as weak. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue what I found is I didn't make weak reference for my other class delegate

```
protocol SomeClassDelegate : AnyObject {
    func someClassDelegateMethod(<param>)
}

class SomeClass: NSObject {

    // Make delegate weak reference 
    weak var delegate:InfractionDataManagerDelegate? = nil
    < some code >
}
```

now **deinit** is being called on my implementation class.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add an edge case which I found very difficult to detect:

If you allocate any UnsafeMutablePointers and provide `self` (the UIViewController) as pointee inside of your view controller, make sure to call `pointer.deinitialize(count:)`, **not** just `pointer.deallocate()`.

Otherwise, the reference to `self` will remain and the UIViewController will not deinitialize.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same Problem. In my case a never ending cycle of UIView.animateWithDuration... holds the ViewController in Memory and blocks the call of deinit. If you use something like this you have to stop it first bevor you remove the ViewController. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue: I had some `UIViews` as *arranged subviews* of a *stackview" contained in a *scrollview* in a detail view controller. It worked when I removed the `UIViews` from the *stackview* on back button tap (`willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?)`). Another thing to check is when in your view controller you have something like: `let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())` (that `self` could in some cases prevent a detail view controller to be deallocated when you click *Back* and move to the master)

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure to define deinit

```
deinit {
    print("OverlayView deinit")
}
```

Use Xcode's object graph to check number of instances being created and if they are not getting deallocated then they will keep growing.
**I was creating property of another ViewController on top of the file so i move it and place it in the scope it was being used that solved my problem. And its deinit started calling.**

Moreover i was using a uiview property to show a overlay that need to be accessed from my viewcontroller at some places i make it optional and set it nil when after calling removefromsuperview on it.

```
var overlay: OverlayView?
overlay = nil
```

If still dealloc not calling then there could be a retain cycle issue as described above in that case you will have to check another viewcontroller(B) too if its calling back this controller(A) then set one of them as a weak variable.

Answer (score 0):

the most helping material that I could find in this problem is [link](https://www.swiftdevcenter.com/reasons-for-deinit-is-not-getting-called-ios-swift/)

But for me the problem was `typealias`