# How ARC act with force unwrapped instance

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, option-type, deinit

I'mm trying to learn how ARC works exactly, so I read [Swift ARC documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) and I followed the example that they provide in the document using playground:

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    weak var apartment: Apartment?

    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
    deinit { print("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
}

class Apartment {
    let unit: String
    weak var tenant: Person?

    init(unit: String) { self.unit = unit }
    deinit { print("Apartment \(unit) is being deinitialized") }
}

var john: Person?
var unit4A: Apartment?
john = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
unit4A = Apartment(unit: "4A")
john?.apartment = unit4A
unit4A?.tenant = john

john = nil
unit4A = nil
```

My question is why when I call `Person` instance `john` optional:

```
john?.apartment = unit4A
```

the object become deallocated, but when I call it force unwrapped:

```
john!.apartment = unit4A
```

it will not become deallocated.

Comment: Probably related to how Playgrounds handles object references (e.g., incremental compilation, object inspection, etc). Try running this on a regular Xcode project instead (for instance, a simple command line app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing your code in a simple Xcode project worked just fine, this is a problem related to playgrounds handling objects.

However a when a `deinit` is not called its probably a retain cycle problem, 
because the **ARC** is not able to deallocate strong references, therefore wont be deallocated.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41772279/8192960) .
Also read more about retain cycles [here](https://medium.com/mackmobile/avoiding-retain-cycles-in-swift-7b08d50fe3ef)