# Will deinit gets called when a view controller gets disappeared?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, deinit

I created two view controllers like

```
Navigation controller -> View Controller -> Details View Controller
          1                     2                      3
```

The (2) View Controller has a button in it which when clicked will shows (3) Details View Controller. I have created a segue from button to (3) VC.

I have added `deinit` blocks in those two classes.

```
deinit {
    print("vc deinit")
}
```

However, this does not get logged. When will a view controller get deallocated?

[Sample code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f-R8eA071temKqHzgS3VT7TI-nehynuv/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Related (Duplicate?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971415/deinit-never-called

Comment: None of the provided solutions answer this question.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772225/explanation-for-deinit-not-called?rq=1

Comment: Is there any special code that might leads to a retain cycle in the view controllers?

Comment: I have add the sample project to the question.

Comment: Project won't work (no pods exist). However, make sure that the details view controller is connected to `DetailsViewController` class in the interface builder, therefore when tapping back, you should see "details vc deinit" logged.

Comment: Please delete all the pods. I have updated the zip.

Comment: Thanks. That works. When switching to details, why is the previous VC not getting deallocated?

Comment: @jsloop: Your first sketch shows the reason: The navigation controller holds a reference to the first VC.

Comment: @jsloop: More precisely: UINavigationController holds references to *all* VCs in the current navigation stack, via its `viewControllers` property.

Comment: @MartinR even without a UINavigationController (let's say present/dismiss), the initial view controller won't get deallocated since its the root view controller... Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AhmadF: The root view controller is the navigation controller in this case. But yes, this was just a comment, not intended to cover all possible situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the only `deinit` will get called is the second one (the one implemented in the `Details View Controller`) each time you tap the back button on the navigation (pop to the previous view controller).

So, why the first `deinit` (the one in the `View Controller`) didn't get called?

That's because it is the first view controller in the navigation controller *stack*. Pushing to the second view controller does not mean that the previous one(s) one has been deallocated and still exists as the first element in the navigation stack; As an example, that's why `viewDidLoad` method should not get called when you come back from a popped view controller, which means it did not get deallocated.