# ViewController's deinit not called after segue

Tags: swift, memory, uiviewcontroller, root, deinit

I have two test controllers: `TestController1` and `TestController2`. I'm trying to deinit first controller when second controller loaded or appeared by changing `UIApplication.shared.window[0].rootViewController` to self (`TestController2`). But nothing is going on and I also have two controllers in memory. So, my question is: how can I `deinit` all ViewControllers and keeps in memory only one?

All my test controllers have deinit method and I'm trying to print "deinited" when it's executed, so i don't have any problems with break points like in many questions asked here.

This is my `TestController2`'s code:

```
class TestController2: UIViewController {

    deinit {
        print("testController 2 deinited")
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        //first attempt
        let del = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        del.window?.rootViewController = self

        //second attempt
        UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController = self

        //third attempt
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = self
    }
}
```

All my attempts don't work..

Updated: First and second controllers have only one button. No any business logic. I created a segue by ctrl+drag mode on Storyboard from button at controller 1 to controller 2.

Comment: It is impossible to say without having a little more info such as when & how the controllers are initialized, are they strongly referenced by any objects? Also... how are you presenting the second controller?

Comment: @Alladinian i have added this info in my question description

Comment: OS will manage the deinit. Why you want to force De-init ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal i think that can be memory problems

Comment: Tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971415/deinit-never-called

Comment: @UmairAfzal i don't use NavigationController, that's not my case