# Best way to deinit a loading view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a loading view controller when my app starts, when an animation in this view controller finished I want it to show another view controller and dismiss the view controller with the animation.

The loading view controller is the initial view controller,

I have this code when UIStoryboard.mflMainTabBarViewController(). returns the view controller that I want to present

```
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    let animationID = anim.value(forKey: "animationID")
    if animationID as! NSString == "transform" {
        self.present(UIStoryboard.mflMainTabBarViewController(), animated: true, completion: {
            _ = self.popoverPresentationController
        })

    }
}`
```

But when deinit is never called

```
    deinit {
    print("deinit")
}
```

What is the best way to deinit the first view controller, and making the presenting view controller the root view controller?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using weak reference cycle at that time `deinit` method is calling. In strong reference cycle `deinit` not calling. So create weak reference cycle for calling the method.

Also refer [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28202154/1746086)

Comment: even when I add        weak var weakSelf = self
                _ = weakSelf?.popoverPresentationController        deinit isnt called

Comment: its the same, I just replaced self. with weakSelf when doing the popover

Answer (score 0):

try this.

Use the vc's parent to present.

And dismiss the vc itself.

```
self.presentingViewController?.present(UIStoryboard.mflMainTabBarViewController(), animated: true, completion: {
            _ = self.popoverPresentationController
        })
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

or

```
self.navigationController?.present(UIStoryboard.mflMainTabBarViewController(), animated: true, completion: {
            _ = self.popoverPresentationController
        })
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
```

Comment: for some reason, navigationController is nil, do you have any idea was going on ?

Comment: @dmram maybe you're not using push?

Comment: I'm not, my first view controller(the loading view controller) is the initial view controller

Answer (score 0):

**If you are 100% sure that self will never be nil, then just use**

```
    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        let animationID = anim.value(forKey: "animationID")
        if animationID as! NSString == "transform" {
            self.present(UIStoryboard.mflMainTabBarViewController(), animated: true, completion: { [unowned self] in
                _ = self.popoverPresentationController
            })

        }
 }`
```

`weak` and `unowned` are the same. Except one thing. Unlike `weak` we’ve seen, `unowned` does not automatically convert `self` as optional within the closure block.